# Downloading folders with files in them from ftp server

Tags: python, gzip, ftplib

I've created a function which download .gz files from given ftp server and uncommpressing them on the fly, but in this case directory which I'm accessing has subdirectories. I want to download all this subdirectories and all files that are in them and i want files to be uncompressed too. How should I modify this function?

```
ionex_domain = "ftp://cddis.gsfc.nasa.gov/gnss/products/troposphere/zpd/" #domain with subdirectories
year = '2013'

    def download(ionex_domain, year):
        user = getpass.getuser()
        ionex_parse = urlparse(ionex_domain) 
    
        ionex_connection = FTP(ionex_parse.netloc)
        ionex_connection.login()
        ionex_connection.cwd(ionex_parse.path + year)
        ionex_files = ionex_connection.nlst()
    
        ionex_userpath = "C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\DCBviz\\ionex\\" + year
        pathlib.Path(ionex_userpath).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True) 
        
        if os.path.exists(ionex_userpath):
            shutil.rmtree(ionex_userpath)
            os.makedirs(ionex_userpath)
    
        for fileName in ionex_files:
            local_filename = os.path.join(ionex_userpath, fileName)
            if local_filename.endswith('.gz'):
                local_filename = local_filename[:-3]
            data = BytesIO()
            ionex_connection.retrbinary('RETR '+ fileName, data.write, 1024)
            data.seek(0)
            uncompressed = gzip.decompress(data.read())
            with open(local_filename, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(uncompressed)
    download(ionex_domain, year)
```

Comment: You could try to use recursion.

Comment: but how should I implement it in this code?

Comment: You could modify it so that you have a method that receives the path of a directory to download, dowloads the files in that directory and then for every subdirectory calls the same method using the path of the subdirectory.